# CakePHP str_replace errors?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to setup my CakePHP project on a localhost environment, but i get this error:

```
Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($replace) of type array|string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bakesystem\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Utility\Text.php on line 232
```

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($replace) of type array|string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bakesystem\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Utility\Text.php on line 232

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($replace) of type array|string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bakesystem\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Utility\Text.php on line 232

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($replace) of type array|string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bakesystem\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Utility\Text.php on line 232

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($replace) of type array|string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bakesystem\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Utility\Text.php on line 232

And then i get like 30 of these errors...

After all these errors gets printed out, the rest displays fine. I can obviously toggle errors off and keep going, but i would like to fix the error if possible.

Can anyone direct me to anything that might help me? I'm kinda lost as to how i can debug this and resolve it...

Comment: These errors are coming from CakePHP itself so you would need to submit a patch to CakePHP to resolve them. They are "deprecation" errors, which means they are telling you about something which works currently but won't in a future version of PHP, you can ignore them and still show other errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL ~ E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: Make sure you're using a CakePHP version that's supports your PHP version.

Comment: Are you on Windows? When I'm on Windows, I use WAMP, with PHP 7.4.29 +, and cakephp works just fine with that setup, and the latest version of cakephp.

Comment: Looks like this notice is likely coming from the `Text::insert` function in CakePHP, so there's an excellent chance that the issue is not actually in Cake code, but in the parameter(s) you're passing to it. Look further back in the stack trace to find where your code is involved, and see what's going on there; you might be passing an array with null values in it instead of blank strings, for example.

Comment: You are using a totally outdated Cake version. Update and it will work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

php is getting more and more strict. It is not a CakePHP issue.
Your issue is based on passing null to a function which doesn't accept null anymore. Often these issues can be solved by null checking before calling function like:

```
 if ($search !== null && $replace !== null && $subject !== null) {
     str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
 }
```

or by casting to string (if it is a string or null) like:

```
 str_replace((string)$search, (string)$replace, (string)$subject);
```

Of course you can skip the cast or the null checking if you know it cannot be null.